# Returning Multiple Header Names based on same multiple cell values

Tags: excel, inventory-management

I'm trying to create a system where I can allocate individual order numbers to a shelf location or multiple shelf locations (because sometimes I have 2 or more products in one order that is then located to two different locations).

I've looked around, and I seem to not be able to find a good way to create a formula that does a more specific action, however, I did come across this post on here and it is close to what I need to do, but it only results in one answer, unless I am not looking at that formula example correctly.

[How do I return the column header matching multiple criteria using Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732104/how-do-i-return-the-column-header-matching-multiple-criteria-using-excel)

In that post, the result Gemini is for Unique ID 42370.6433, but what if lets say it was also Silver for Parks. So that would result in both Gemini and Parks.

I've come across many examples of Index/Match, Aggregate, but they don't seem to result to what I'm looking for.

If this has been answers before, would you please re-direct me there, because I am not sure anymore if I am wording my search the way it has been asked in the past.

Thank you!

Comment: if you want the output of multiple returns in one cell then it will require vba unless you have office 365 excel.  Please also include your own data set and expected output

Comment: you're question is almost impossible to answer without sample data. Please edit your question to include how the data looks now and describe clearly whch result you expect in which cell. It is also usefull to state if you would accept using a vba macro as a solution of if you are searching for a formula.